# How to make the beginning and the end of a method reusable?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

**How would I create a more generic method?**

I've got a method:

```
        public ServiceAppointment UpdateService(Guid serviceGuid, Guid serviceActivityGuid)
        {
//this is repeated in 20 methods
            var serviceAppointment = organizationService.Retrieve(
                "serviceappointment",
                serviceActivityGuid,
                new ColumnSet(true));
//end
//Only the section here will vary
            serviceAppointment["serviceid"] = new EntityReference("service", serviceGuid);
//End

//this is repeated in 20 methods
            organizationService.Update(serviceAppointment);

            return GetServiceActivity(serviceActivityGuid);
//end
        }
```

As you can see from above, only this section will change from method to method:

```
serviceAppointment["serviceid"] = new EntityReference("service", serviceGuid);
```

**Is it possible to create a method that will run the beginning and the ending of the method above and accept as a parameter the line that changes?**

Comment: Put code at the begin in one method and at the end in another and call those methods when needed.

Comment: @Roma That wouldn't work well here.  The two methods have state that is shared between just those two snippets of code, and they're highly coupled; they need to always be called together, with a particular operation happening between them, and not separately.  They don't really work as their own separate methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a delegate to inject the difference:

```
public ServiceAppointment UpdateService(Guid serviceGuid, Guid serviceActivityGuid, Action<Entity> action)
{
    var serviceAppointment = organizationService.Retrieve(
            "serviceappointment",
            serviceActivityGuid,
            new ColumnSet(true));

    action(serviceAppointment);

    organizationService.Update(serviceAppointment);

    return GetServiceActivity(serviceActivityGuid);
}
```

Calling this would be:

```
UpdateService(serviceGuid, serviceActivityGuid, 
    e => e["serviceid"] = new EntityReference("service", serviceGuid));
```

Comment: I could not, from your code, determine what OrganizationService.Retrieve returned (I erroneously assumed ServiceAppointment because of the variable naming). Take whatever the type being returned by OrganizationService.Retrieve (Entity?) and change the action parameter to that (e.g. Action<Entity> action).

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are how you have a method accept code to execute as a parameter.  In your case, you want a method that accepts a `serviceAppointment` as a parameter and provides no output as the method `UpdateService` should accept, that's an `Action<ServiceAppointment>`.  The caller can then provide a (possibly anonymous) method that simply sets the appropriate values of that service appointment.

Comment: can you show me how i would create the anonymous method to pass?

Comment: @MeggieLuski You can [look it up in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx).